# Writing file from PHP (Yii) at runtime on GAE ( app engine )

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yii

I'm trying to deploy yii 2 locally on app engine sdk. Yii creates and publishes assets at runtime in the /web/assets directory. But GAE docs say An App Engine PHP app must use either Cloud Storage stream wrapper to write files at runtime. How do I configure this 'gs://...' stuff to publish the assets and for logging in Yii-2? Any other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: What is it about the documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/  that is unclear ?  What have you tried so far.

Comment: e.g.  the name of my bucket on localhost, how to create new buckets (or is it not possible?)

Comment: I suggest that comment should have been in your original question.